# modular JAX-RS jersey resources (REST resources in a jar)

Tags: java, rest, struts, jersey

Pardon my ignorance. I have struts 1.2 app deployed on jboss. I have a jar which contains jersey REST resources. How do I expose the resources present in the jar file through my struts app? Basically I need a way by which my struts app can find the REST resources in the jar file and expose them.